# Function slows down after upgrading npm packages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I've upgraded an application that uses vue/vuex/vuetify to the latest npm packages, (actually from Vuetify 1.5 to 2.0 and for other packages just minor versions), and although it works, one function in vuex store that uses `reduce()` seems to have slowed down from 500ms to almost 10s.

Timings are from *Chrome DevTools -> Performance*.

I've replaced `reduce()` with a `forEach()` loop and that speeds it up like before. However, I can't seem to find out why it slowed down in the first place? I suspect that compilation process has changed somehow?

vuex store slow code (only after upgrade):

```js
 var x = items.reduce((acc, item) => { 
    return {[item.id]: item, ...acc}
 });
```

fast code in both cases:

```js
 items.forEach(el => {
     x[el.id] = el;
 });
```

[image: fast run]
[image: slow run]

Comment: Are you using Babel? If so, which version was it before and what version is it now?

Answer (score 3):

Well the `.reduce()` code creates a new object on every iteration, copying all the properties from the previous accumulator object. If there are a *lot* of items, that's a large amount of work; it's what you'd call an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

Instead of making a new object, new properties can be added to the existing object:

```
var x = items.reduce((acc, item) => { 
    acc[item.id] = item;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

That's an O(n) process (n being the number of items in the array).

Comment: That's true but it was fast before the upgrade with the same data!  Thanks for the alternative code.

Comment: @nkms I don't know much about what's going on in your application; it could be that the number of items increased a whole lot. (I don't know what "items" is even.)

Comment: @nkms also 500ms seems like a lot of processing time to me. The unnecessary creation of all those new objects, and the repeated copying and re-copying of all those properties, is a less-than-ideal way of doing things in general.

Comment: Could make a good anti-pattern question out of this. See it a lot in SO answers that use reduce  probably because *"spread is cool"* and can make a leaner code implicit return using it

Comment: @charlietfl yea questions that include "I want to use spread" make my head hurt a little, also "I want to use an arrow function"